# Change the color of an option when selected

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, html-select, onchange

I want an option to change color when selected by a user. For Example: a user selects the red option then a function would run that would change the color red. If the user then selected green then it would change green. etc.

```
<select onchange="changeColor();" class="color" id="rgb">
  <option id="red" value="Red">Red</option>
  <option id="green" value="Green">Green</option>
  <option id="blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

I started with the function below but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
function changeColor() {
    var red = document.getElementById('red');
    var green = document.getElementById('green');
    var blue = document.getElementById('blue');

    if(event.target.value == red) {
      red.style.color = "red";
    } else if(event.target.value == green) {
      green.style.color = "green";
    } else if(event.target.value == blue) {
      blue.style.color = "blue";
    } else  {
      alert("There was an error!");
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't added an 'event' parameter to your function. Try this:

```
function changeColor(event) {
  var red = document.getElementById(red);
  var green = document.getElementById(green);
  var blue = document.getElementById(blue);

  if (event.target.value == red) {
    red.style.color = "red";
  } else if (event.target.value == green) {
    green.style.color = "green";
  } else if (event.target.value == blue) {
    blue.style.color = "blue";
  } else {
    alert("There was an error!");
  }};
```

Comment: that's only 1/2 of how to add it

Answer (score 1):

Try this. When you select an option you will recieve the `<select>` element in `colorParam`. If you select the first option, you will get `Red` in `colorParam.value`, but you are using IDs in lowerCase, so you can use `toLowerCase()` function to convert it. Then select the `option` element and apply styles.

```js
function changeColor(colorParam) {
    let color = colorParam.value.toLowerCase();
    var optionElement = document.getElementById(color);
    optionElement.style.color = color;
};
```

```html
<select onchange="changeColor(this);" class="color" id="rgb">
  <option id="red" value="Red">Red</option>
  <option id="green" value="Green">Green</option>
  <option id="blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option id="white" value="White">White</option>
  <option id="pink" value="Pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can style an `<option>` element. You can style the `<select>` element though. However, `color` doesn't seem to be a property you can change, `background-color` is.

If that's all you need you could as well inline the javascript code in the `onchange` handler attribute. You would need to set the values of the `<option>` elements to valid css colours.

```html
<select onchange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.value">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check onchange only selected value color will get changed.
```

```js
$(function() {
//The color of the selected value changed
  jQuery("#state-list").on("change", function() {

    if (jQuery(this).val()) {
    
  let colorselect= jQuery(this).find("option:selected").attr('id');
  jQuery('.statetext option').css("color", "#919ca1");
  jQuery('.statetext').find("option:selected").css("color",  colorselect);
  jQuery('.statetext').css("color",  colorselect)
  } else {
  jQuery('.statetext').css("color", "#919ca1");
  jQuery('.statetext option').css("color", "#919ca1");
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="state-list" name="State" data-name="State" class="statetext"  style="color: rgb(145, 156, 161);">
<option value="">State</option>
<option value="CA"  id="red">CA</option>
<option value="BC" id="yellow">BC</option>
<option value="DE" id="green">DE</option></select>
```